# Make navigation menu buttons highlighted for the current page

Tags: php, menu, navigation

I have created a navigation menu that loads different "includes" on the same page. I want the menu buttons to stay highlighted for the current page. All the answer I have seen here only deal with navigating to a different page for each link. Is is possible to do it on the same page? Because the navigation bar doesn't actually reload.

```
 <nav class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="menuitem"><a href="?link=1" name="fluidBalance" <?php echo ($_GET['link'] == 1) ? 'class="highlight"' : ''; ?>>Calculated Fluid Balance</a></li>
            <li class="menuitem"><a href="?link=2" name="actualFluidBalance" <?php echo ($_GET['link'] == 2) ? 'class="highlight"' : '';?>>Actual Fluid Balance</a></li>
            <li class="menuitem"><a href="?link=3" name="graphicalView" <?php echo ($_GET['link'] == 3) ? 'class="highlight"' : ''; ?>>Graphical View</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
  <div class="contentFluidBalance" id="mainSection">
<?php

 if(isset($_GET['link'])){
     $link=$_GET['link'];
     if ($link == '1'){
         include 'includes/fluidBalance1.php';
      }
     if ($link == '2'){
         include 'includes/fluidBalance2.php';
      }
    if ($link == '3'){
        include 'includes/fluidBalance5.php';
      }
    }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
<nav class="menu">
             <ul>
                 <li class="menuitem"><a href="?link=1" name="fluidBalance" <?php echo ($_GET['link'] == 1) ? 'class="highlight"' : ''; ?>>Calculated Fluid Balance</a></li>
                 <li class="menuitem"><a href="?link=2" name="actualFluidBalance"  <?php echo ($_GET['link'] == 2) ? 'class="highlight"' : '';?>>Actual Fluid Balance</a></li>
                 <li class="menuitem"><a href="?link=3" name="graphicalView"  <?php echo ($_GET['link'] == 3) ? 'class="highlight"' : ''; ?>>Graphical View</a></li>
            </ul>
</nav>
```

where class="highlight" is the name of the class to highlight the menu.

Comment: I have added the php you recommended (see above). Didn't work. Only difference that now even the hover and active options for menu button class don't work either.

Comment: Please check the css.

Comment: Well. For the css I have just included whatever was in the hover:   .highlight {
 color:#ffffff;
 background:#383838;
}

Answer (score 0):

In the end The following code worked for me:

```
<nav class="menu">
 <ul>
   <li<?php if (isset($_GET['link']) && $_GET['link'] == '1') echo 'class="current"'?>><a href="?link=1" <?php if (isset($_GET['link']) && $_GET['link'] == '1') echo ' class="current"'?>" name="fluidBalance">Calculated Fluid Balance</a></li>
   <li<?php if (isset($_GET['link']) && $_GET['link'] == '2') echo ' class="current"'?>><a href="?link=2" <?php if (isset($_GET['link']) && $_GET['link'] == '2') echo ' class="current"'?>" name="actualFluidBalance">Actual Fluid Balance</a></li>
   <li<?php if (isset($_GET['link']) && $_GET['link'] == '3') echo ' class="current"'?>><a href="?link=3" <?php if (isset($_GET['link']) && $_GET['link'] == '3') echo ' class="current"'?>" name="graphicalView">Graphical View</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

<div class="contentFluidBalance" id="mainSection">
  <?php
     if(isset($_GET['link'])) {
      $link=$_GET['link'];

       if ($link == '1'){
        include 'includes/fluidBalance1.php';
      }
      if ($link == '2'){
        include 'includes/fluidBalance2.php';
      }
      if ($link == '3'){
        include 'includes/fluidBalance5.php';
      }
    }
  ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

First, check if the current page is equal to one of your menuitem :

```
<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="menuitem <?php if (isset($_GET['link']) && $_GET['link'] == '1') : ?>current<?php endif; ?>"><a href="?link=1" name="fluidBalance">Calculated Fluid Balance</a></li>
    <li class="menuitem <?php if (isset($_GET['link']) && $_GET['link'] == '2') : ?>current<?php endif; ?>"><a href="?link=2" name="actualFluidBalance">Actual Fluid Balance</a></li>
    <li class="menuitem <?php if (isset($_GET['link']) && $_GET['link'] == '3') : ?>current<?php endif; ?>"><a href="?link=3" name="graphicalView">Graphical View</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="contentFluidBalance" id="mainSection">
  <?php
    if(isset($_GET['link'])) {
      $link=$_GET['link'];

      if ($link == '1'){
        include 'includes/fluidBalance1.php';
      }
      if ($link == '2'){
        include 'includes/fluidBalance2.php';
      }
      if ($link == '3'){
        include 'includes/fluidBalance3.php';
      }
    }
  ?>
</div>
```

Then, in your CSS, do whatever you want with the current class :

```
.menuitem.current a {
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, still doesn't work. It now produces the following error on the initial page, before selecting a menu item: Notice: Undefined index: link in C:\wamp\www\OneDrive\Fluid Accounting ver 2\fluidBalance.php on line 13 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0020245296{main}( )..\fluidBalance.php:0 ">

Comment: Edited the CSS, does the current link is red when you click on it ? I tested it, it should work.

Comment: No. No effect at all.

Comment: Tested it again on PhpFiddle, the link is red when I click on it. http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/y31j-a0zd